# How can I find *.desktop files?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

To the best of my knowledge, all shortcuts in the Unity Launcher have a corresponding *.desktop file. I have one shortcut (for [skrooge](http://skrooge.org/)) that doesn't have an icon. How can I find the *.desktop file corresponding to this shortcut so that I can add an icon to it?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

It's probably sitting in `/usr/share/applications/` but if you want to find every `.desktop` file on the system run this:

```
find / -name '*.desktop'
```

or

```
sudo updatedb
locate *.desktop
```

To find files with "skrooge" in their path or name, add a *grep* to the command:

```
locate *.desktop | grep -iR "skrooge"
```

Comment: `locate -i "*skrooge*.desktop"`. Though there's mainly three places unity will look for desktop files. `~/.local/share/applications`, `/usr/local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications`. If there are desktop files for the same command in multiple places, it'll use the left-most of the three I listed.

Comment: Showed up as `/usr/share/applications/kde4/skrooge.desktop`. Thanks. :)

Comment: This is super useful! Thank you. Note that using `locate *.desktop` helped me discover that desktop files from `snap` package installs seem to go into the `/snap/` and `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directories.

Comment: `locate *.desktop` doesn't find anything. `find / -name '*.desktop' 2> /dev/null` to suppress the 'permission denied' flood.

Comment: And `~/.local/share/applications` is where you put your desktop files so that in Activities window can find it and add it to Favorite (anchor it on deck).

Comment: The XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable controls which directories the launcher will check for *.desktop files.  See @OndroMih's [answer](/a/1348668/1036845) to search in those directories.

Answer (score 56):

The system stores the .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications/`. Unfortunately, if you open that folder in nautilus the .desktop files appears with the icon specified in the file and with the file name called out within the file. You also won't be allowed to edit these files by clicking on them and selecting edit.

To edit these files, you need to open that folder within a terminal window. Doing an `ls` command will show all the .desktop files with their actual names. When you locate the .desktop you wish to change, run `gksudo gedit {file-name}.desktop`.

It's normal practice to keep any .desktop files you create or edit in your home folder `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Running from the terminal can be handier for some, but it is also possible to drag from nautilus into gedit or another text editor.

Comment: what's the point of the directory "~/.local/share/applications"? Files there don't seem to be used, not I cannot add them as "shortcut" to Unity.

Comment: @Malachiasz Actually, the *.desktop files from `~/.local/share/applications` are reloaded when session restarts. So, log out and log back in. Note that these are specific to that user.

Comment: I also found this Q&A here on site useful: [How to force Unity reload ~/.local/share/applications/](https://askubuntu.com/q/375975/55951)

Comment: Does copying a desktop file from `/usr/share/applications` override the entry in `~/.local/share/applications`? I'm trying to configure Firefox to use `firejail`, but whenever the browser updates my edits are removed if I do it in the desktop file from `/usr/share/applications/`.

Comment: Don't forget that snap applications store their `.desktop` files in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`

Answer (score 36):

Some **additional details** to supplement the other answers:

Typically, `.desktop` files for packages will be located in `/usr/share/applications`.

If you want, you could copy one to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit it there **without needing sudo**. Items in `~/.local/share/applications` will **override** matching items in `/usr/share/applications` and `/usr/local/share/applications`, but are only visible to your user.

Alternatively, you could place an edited copy in `/usr/local/share/applications` where it will override any in `/usr/share/applications` while also being visible to the entire system.

Note that you should not edit the `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` directly; any changes you make will be **automatically overwritten** when the application is updated by the package manager.

Extracted from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365232)

Comment: +1, most complete answer out of all of them

Comment: Don't forget that snap applications store their `.desktop` files in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`

Answer (score 21):

You can find all directories with desktop files in the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable. The `*.desktop` files can be in the `applications` directory in each of the directory in that variable. E.g.:

```sh
> echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

You can use this bash script to list all desktop files used by the system (e.g. to build the panel or applications menu):

```sh
for p in ${XDG_DATA_DIRS//:/ }; do 
  find $p/applications -name '*.desktop' 
done
```

It seems that desktop files can also be placed in one more directory, which isn't in the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` variable:

- `~/.local/share/applications`

So, the complete script to find all `*.desktop` files in the system is:

```sh
DATA_DIRS="$XDG_DATA_DIRS:$HOME/.local/share"
for p in ${DATA_DIRS//:/ }; do
  find $p/applications -name '*.desktop' 
done
```

I didn't find any documentation for this but there's some information about this environment variable here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531664

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: This is missing `~/.local/share/applications` and `~/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` isn't it?

Comment: @lrkwz *`/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`

Comment: Freedesktop.org (formerly the X Desktop Group) maintains the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) which includes the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable.  The spec is used beyond the Unity Launcher; [Google's ChromeOS Crostini](https://support.google.com/pixelbook/thread/708306/how-do-i-add-linux-apps-to-the-home-screen?hl=en) and [Microsoft's WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#wsl-dynamic-virtual-channel-plugin-wsldvcplugin) also use it to integrate GNU/Linux programs into their respective UIs.

Comment: @lrkwz I found `/home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications` and `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` in my `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable.

Comment: I think that the value of the XDG_DATA_DIRS variable depends on the version of the system. On my system (Ubuntu Focal 20.04) it contains /var/lib/snapd/desktop but it doesn't contain ~/.local/share. On the other hand, the desktop files in my ~/.local/share/applications aren't displayed in the system menu, so I think that this location isn't supported in my system by default. It's possible that it's supported on a newer version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

Desktop files of snap packages can be found in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` and below `/snap/`.

Comment: In what order are they looked up, relative to `~/.local/share/applications` and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`?

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party, but I have a faster solution than the one accepted as the answer:

```
find / -iname "*desktop" -type f -not -path "/media*" -exec grep -il skrooge '{}' ';' 2> /dev/null
```

It's faster because it doesn't search the data mounted file systems and most probably the desktop file is located in the system partition.

Moreover, it's more likely to find what the command from the accepted answer would miss. That's because the desktop files doesn't have to hold the application name. This command actually searches the text in every desktop file.

Comment: This did not work for me at all (not even with sudo). I am using Manjaro linux though, but the command should work independent of the OS as long as it has `find`, `grep`. It results in a crash of the command printing nothing.

Comment: @RahatZaman, what's the output of running the command?

Comment: there is no output. After 2-3 minutes, it just returns back to the shell prompt.

Comment: You mentioned *crash* in your first comment. What do you mean by it? Also, where do drives get mounted in Manjaro? Did you update **skrooge** to the application you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

- `/usr/share/applications` (most applications, admin rights)
- `~/.local/share/applications` (personal ones)

Comment: These answers have already been provided in the two top voted answers in much more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Commandline output for all .desktop files in your system.

`sudo find / -type f -name "*.desktop" -exec echo $PATH {} \;`

This one will dump the terminal spew out to a text file on your desktop so you can actually read it.

`sudo find / -type f -name "*.desktop" -exec echo $PATH {} \; 1>~/Desktop/Desktop-files-output.txt`

once found, if its not in `/usr/share/applications` you can do `sudo ln -s [the .desktop name] /usr/share/applications/[the .desktop name]` which will add a link to that directory and make it appear in your applications menu.

if it is in there; change or add these lines to the .desktop file;

`NoDisplay=false`
`Hidden=false`

If it doesn't have a .desktop, you can make one;

```
cat>>Skrooge.desktop<<EOL
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=name
Comment=[what it does]
Path=/working/directory/comment/this/out/if/you/are/going/to/use/$HOME
Exec=[the command line command you use to launch it.]
Icon=/usr/share/icons/icon.png
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
Categories=menucategory1;category2
Terminal=false[unless its a commandline only program like htop]
EOL
```

Then run `chmod +x Skrooge.desktop`

Once made and proven to work, drop it in `/usr/share/applications` so it shows up in your applications menu.

Comment: Have you actually ran that find command?

Comment: Yes @muru, I've ran that find command before. it outputs all non-errors to a file on the desktop. It requires root to work properly. its about as harmful as a `sudo ls` command.

Comment: Really, that exact command with the `$PATH` in it?

Answer (score -3):

I do not actually now which .desktop file becomes effective. My best guess is, from  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries , to make a script like this and run it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# try to find the effective desktop file
# (there seems to be no documented standard for this)

use_if_desktop_file () {
  if [ -r "$1" ] &&
     [ "$(xdg-mime query filetype "$1")" = application/x-desktop ]; then
       echo "$1"
       exit
  fi
}

for d in ~/.local/share/applications /usr/local/share/applications \
         /usr/share/applications; do
  use_if_desktop_file "$d/$1"
  use_if_desktop_file "$d/$1.desktop"
done

# no file found
exit 1
```