# Script to find executable based on extension of a file?

Tags: bash, mime-type

I need to create a script that returns the default app to be used for a given file extension (including the path). I had a look at the `file` command which can return the mime type and `xdg-open` which would open a file. But what I'd like to get is

```
myscript doc
```

> > /usr/bin/libreoffice

.or.

```
myscript fun
```

> > /opt/acme/roadrunner/meepmeep

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grabbed a Linux expert in the office and we found a reasonable solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXTENSION=$1
SAMPLENAME=$HOME/~webdavhelpersample.$EXTENSION
touch $SAMPLENAME
CURMINE=$(xdg-mime query filetype $SAMPLENAME)
rm $SAMPLENAME
CURDSK=$(xdg-mime query default $CURMINE)

if [ -f /.local/share/applications/$CURDSK ]; then
    TRUEDSK=/.local/share/applications/$CURDSK
elif [ -f /usr/local/share/applications/$CURDSK ]; then
    TRUEDSK=/usr/local/share/applications/$CURDSK
elif [ -f  /usr/share/applications/$CURDSK ]; then
    TRUEDSK=/usr/share/applications/$CURDSK
else 
    echo "Sorry no executable found for $1"
    exit 1
fi

WHATTODO=$(grep "^Exec" $TRUEDSK | head -1)
echo $WHATTODO
```

Once we figured that there are only [3 locations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117341/how-can-i-find-desktop-files) for the desktop files it was not hard anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The command can be something like:

```
xdg-mime query default `xdg-mime query filetype example.odp`
```

Result:

```
libreoffice-impress.desktop
```

Comment: Hi Samik, thx for the reply. I tried the command on Ubuntu 12.04 and ran into 2 problems: a) if example.odp doesn't exist it just throws an error and secondly (the bigger issue) I just got *application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation* in return. Also the desktop file doesn't execute, I need to have something I can call with a set of parameters thereafter

Comment: Quick update: I can get to the desktop file using *xdg-mime query filetype example.odp || xdg-mime query default* but then still the challenge is how to get to the executable including the path