# Cannot Remove Microsoft Office 2007 icons

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, software-uninstall

I tried to install MS Office 2007 through Wine. Now that I have uninstalled Wine, and when I search the term "word", the Microsoft Office Word Icon still appears. How do I remove it completely from my system? I deleted the .wine folder too, but the icons still appear once I search the term "word".

Comment: use this method http://askubuntu.com/questions/117341/how-can-i-find-desktop-files to find .desktop (link) to your app and remove it. if the program itself was installed in standard directory and you want to remove it as well, then removal of ~/.wine should remove all installed apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall a program installed with Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine)

Comment: @IvanTemchenko that is not the easiest method.

Answer (score 3):

Friends, I finally sorted out this weird problem. As soon as I deleted the contents of /home/username/.local/share/applications/wine
the icons were gone!
But anyways, thanks a lot for giving me hints. Your comments helped me sort out this problem!