# set new icon for rxvt-unicode

Tags: command-line, icons, customization

I am trying to use a numix icon for rxvt-unicode. I haven't found much recent discussion on this topic but the thread I was following was:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166210

my /.Xdefaults looks like:

```
URxvt*iconFile: /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/scalable/apps/xterm-color.svg
```

when starting URxvt through my current terminal with `rxvt-unicode` I receive: `"urxvt: Loading image icon failed, continuing without."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to pretty much fix my problem. I made edits to the rxvt-unicode.desktop file changing the icon to one of my choosing. At that point I was able to see the new icon when loading rxvt-unicode from the unity launcher or sidebar. Information on finding the .desktop files can be found here: [How can I find *.desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117341/how-can-i-find-desktop-files)

One thing I noticed though is if I use another terminal to launch rxvt-unicode it still shows the old icon. Not sure yet why that is happening. This only has become a problem because I created a keyboard shortcut to make `Super+q` launch a terminal and it does that through the terminal as far as I can tell.