# Why is this file name truncated in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, files, gui, .desktop

In Ubuntu the "extension" to a file name, that is, the part after the dot (.) is normally visible. Why is Nautilus not showing the extension of `eclipse.desktop` when the `ls` command clearly shows that is the full file name?

This is the `list view`; not the `icon view`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Simply because . desktop files are recognized as application shortcuts. No great mystery there. Feel free to explore Nautilus source code to find how exactly it's done.

Comment: By that reason, `smartgit.desktop` is not an application shortcut. What is `smartgit.desktop`?

Comment: For it to be recognised that way, it also has to be executable, IIRC..

Comment: This seems unjustified. Executable bash scripts do not have this problem. 
A "binary" executable like java does not have this problem. To experiment I renamed java (a file that is executable) to x.x to demonstrate that the file name is not truncated.

Comment: Hi @H2ONaCl .desktop files are special files, see my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### About .desktop files and their special function

`.desktop` files are special files. They *represent* applications in the GUI, either on your desktop or in Dash/Unity. To do so, a ***GUI*** -name of the application is set in a line inside the file in the line

```
Name=Eclipse
```

You can simply change the name of how the application shows in Dash and Unity, by changing this line inside the `.desktop` file, without changing the *file* name of the `.desktop` file. In that case, it is irrelevant if the file is executable or not.

If the `.desktop` file is *on your desktop* however, if it is *not* executable, it does not work as a launcher, for reasons explained in souravac's answer, and "shows" under its own (file) name:

```
eclipse.desktop
```

If it *is* executable and on your desktop, it works as a launcher and so it is is representing an application. *Then* it shows the application's name, as set in the line `Name=`

#### Language specific name

If the `.desktop` file has the line:

```
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain
```

the file even shows a language- specific name, fetched from a language file, which will then show in Dash and Unity.

*below a complicated example: filename = inkskape.desktop, "basic" interface name = Inkskape, translated name = Inkskape Vector Graphics Editor*

[image]

#### The ls command

In the `ls` command is purely cli- based and always shows the *file* -name.

Comment: It seems useful for .desktop files to be special when they are on the ~/Desktop. It seems strange to me that they are special when they are at ~/.local/share/applications.

Comment: @H2ONaCl True, they do not need to be executable there, also not in /usr/share/applications most of the are not executable there and show their own name. Just look inside the directory. Dash/Unity reads their Name= -line then.

Comment: They do need to be executable anywhere under user's home directory. See screenshot from my desktop: http://imgur.com/a/bTXYj  Without executable permissions set, it is not runable. Desktop is just a special case of a nautilus window, but same rules apply

Comment: @JacobVlijm I was responding to H2ONaCl about the files being special. I've no problem with your answer

Comment: @JacobVlijm I forget to do that sometimes

Comment: @Serg you have contradicted Jacob Vlijm when you said they need to be executable under the home directory. ~/.local/share/applications is under the home directory and it has been said they do NOT need to be executable there.

Comment: I selected this as the preferred answer because it is informative as well as being correct but if it is TLDR (Too Long; Don't Read) then Jacob Vlijm's comment that `.desktop files are special` is a superior answer. My own answer appearing (probably below) is that this behavior is a quirk. That would also be a good short answer.

Answer (score 20):

Quoting from [Ubuntu's security policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Policies#Execute-Permission_Bit_Required):

> **Execute-Permission Bit Required**
>
> - Applications, including desktops and shells, must not run executable code from files when they are both:
>
>   - lacking the executable bit
>   - located in a user's home directory or temporary directory.
> - This includes *.desktop, *.jar, and *.exe files.

***What is a valid `.desktop` file under user's home directory?***

According to Ubuntu's security policy the execution permission in `.desktops` files and shells script is a must to run executable code from those files when they are located in a user's home directory.

Nautilus will not consider a `.desktop` file as valid application shortcuts unless it has executable bit when they are located in a user's home directory.

On the other hand it is hard coded in nautilus's source code that it will show a valid `.desktop` file's name from the `Name=` or `Name[$LANG]` field inside the `.desktop` file  ignoring the filename and extension. This does not apply to `.sh` or `.jar` files in nautilus.

**Example:** On a fresh Ubuntu installation every user gets `examples.desktop` in their home directory. The file name is `examples.desktop`. But in nautilus one can see it as `Examples`. If you look inside the `.desktop` file you can see following (I am showing only part of it):

```
Name=Examples
Name[aa]=Ceelallo
..
Name[en_AU]=Examples
Name[en_CA]=Examples
Name[en_GB]=Examples
..
```

You can check the permission (try `ls -la /path/to/filename.extension`) of `Eclipse.desktop` and `smartgit.desktop`. The former has executable bit set whereas the later has not.

That is why nautilus is recognizing `Eclipse.desktop` as application shortcuts and not showing its extension.

Comment: Yep, exactly that. Good job for providing the link as well. Good answer

Comment: I have many executables under ~/Documents/bashscripts which are "under" the home directory and yet Nautilus shows the file name extension of my *.sh files. This is true in list view and icon view. I have also copied java to the file x.x. Copying java to the file x.x keeps the executable permission of the original java file. Nautilus shows the file name to be x.x in both list view and icon view. What you say about executables does not seem to apply in these cases so in general it seems wrong to say that the executable bit causes the extension to be truncated from Nautilus.

Comment: The quote you cited seems to have nothing to do with file name truncation in Nautilus. It seems to describe the necessity of the execute bit.

Comment: @H2ONaCl it does have to do with filename truncation. Once a .desktop file is executable, the Name of application set inside the file can be set.  Say you can have `myapp.desktop` and it has `Name=Some Cool App` line. With executable permission set, only then filename can be displayed as `Some Cool App`.  Of course, the file must be in proper format,too, and actually have that `Name=` line.  By the way , see souravc's edited answer, it was updated.

Comment: @H2ONaCl see also http://askubuntu.com/q/419610/295286  Related.

Answer (score 6):

If a `.desktop` file is executable then Nautilus will recognize it as a desktop shortcut and will not display the name of the file, but rather the string set as the value of the `Name=` property in the file.

Comment: This may be true but for me it is unexpected when Nautilus is displaying files in ~/.local/share/applications/. Copying this file to ~/anyDirectory/ still results in a truncated file name. Neither of these places is the ~/Desktop.

Comment: Doesn't have to be in the ~/Desktop folder.  The file name _is not truncated_. It's not displayed _at all_. Nautilus shows the Name= property set in the file.

Comment: Ok, it's not truncated. It only looks that way by coincidence and it really came from inside the file. Why do we need this behavior at all when the authors of the 'ls' command did not see fit to do likewise.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Why *would* it be? The original `ls` command was written before GUIs were even "a thing", and there's no reason for a power-user program to treat one type of file completely differently from all of the others in an environment where the files in question aren't even used.

Answer (score 0):

At this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/117526/25031) author "fragos" writes:

> Unfortunately, if you open that folder in nautilus the .desktop files
>   appears with the icon specified in the file and with the file name
>   called out within the file.

When he says "file name called out within" he means the displayed file name is taken from within. I would say "file name called out within when the executable bit is set". He may be right that this is unfortunate. Strangely I have some that have the execute bit set and some that do not. The ones that do NOT have the execute bit set are not a cause of misfortune but I don't know why I was lucky. When the bit is set perhaps it can be considered a quirk or bug.

Comment: Developers can set the `.desktop` file executable or not. Most of them do not, as you can see in `/usr/share/applications`. There also is no reason to set them executable in there, and they will show their file name in nautilus (not in Unity/Dash). The fact that they *can* be used as a direct launcher makes sense, and so the fact that they show their GUI name then, when made executable.

Comment: That is not nautilus- specific. It all makes completely sense and is definitely not a bug. As mentioned, the *GUI* name, as in Dash/Unity, of a `.desktop` file is flexibel, often even language specific. No bug, that's how it is designed.

Comment: I don't know why you say this makes sense. There is an inconsistency. Some of the files do not have the execute bit set. What purpose do they serve when the bit is not set? If the files that do NOT have the bit set are still functional (and display the full name) then what is the justification for displaying the string taken from inside the file? The point is to examine directories of files just like the 'ls' command. Using the string from inside the file deviates from the behavior of the 'ls' command. How can that deviation be justified?

Comment: The files inside `/usr/share/applications` are not meant as (direct) launchers from the GUI, only to serve the (GUI) interface of the OS, like Unity and Dash in this case. There is no reason for a developer to make the file executable if stored there, nor in `~.local/share/applications`. You can call it a bug if you want, but totally harmless, since it is not meant to use directly, *unless* it is on e.g. your desktop. When used to serve as a representative of your application, A .desktop file is *meant* to behave as a chameleon,  depending on your language etc.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, Thank you for suggesting I can call it a bug if I want. I will settle for calling it a quirk that Nautilus has adopted a behavior meant for Unity on the Desktop or Dash.

Comment: I have no clue what your issue is. It is not a nautilus thing. *all* file explorers behave like this. And they *should*.  .desktop files in the `/usr/share/applications` are meant to be used by Unity, but the *can* be used on your desktop, or anywhere else in `~/home` as a direct launcher. Then they need to be executable, showing the appname they represent. Really, you are fighting windmills here. It all makes *perfectly* sense.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, perhaps this might clarify: from my point of view and perhaps that of other users Nautilus is an application that is distinct from Unity showing the Desktop and Nautilus is an application that is distinct from Unity showing Dash and the Launcher. Nautilus appears to be a counterpart or substitute for `ls` and `cd` and `rm` and so if displays differently from `ls` it surprised me.