# How are there two identical folders in the same location?

Tags: files, directory, duplicate-files, duplicate

[image]

This is a picture of my desktop, with the main folder in which I store pretty much everything. At some point in time, the computer sprouted a twin. They both have the same name, and go to the same place - there are just two of them. The situation concerns me, as it seems like the indexing of my files and folders in this location has also gone awry, and I assume the issues may be linked.

What should I do? I'm pretty sure I can't delete one, as that would delete everything....

Thanks for your help

Comment: One of them possibly is a huge .desktop file, although I have no clue how it would have come into existence. What is the output of `ls ~/Desktop`?

Comment: Is one of them just a link to the other?

Comment: @Jacob, I ran that command, and indeed there is /The Door, and /The Door.desktop .... does that mean it is safe to delete one?

Comment: Seems like that. You could see what is inside it, opening it with `gedit 'The Door.desktop'` , but it seems useless to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### .desktop file

The only possible explanation I can think of is that one of them is a [.desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/a/857927/72216). To find out, run `ls ~/Desktop`, and see if that is the case. [your comment confirmed my suspicion]

***If*** That is the case, you can check what is inside it by running

```
gedit '~/Desktop/The Door.desktop'
```

It seems a pretty useless file though.

The big question is where it came from

Comment: Thanks Jacob. This is the output: ** (gedit:6454): CRITICAL **: file log.c: line 980: unexpected error: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon exited with status 1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 25)

Comment: @Amphibio that is not the content of the file, but a warning. I'd simply remove the file though, since it obviously just opens another directory.

Comment: If I were to delete one from the desktop, how would I know which is the right one? There seems to be no way of telling. Do I cut the red wire or the blue wire???

Comment: @Amphibio the blue one. No, the red one. Nono... :) simply right-click to see properties :)

Comment: From the view of the properties panel, they are identical: folder type: inode/directory, 95,140 items, home/amphibian/Desktop

Comment: Huh? To make sure, i'd do it from the cli: `rm '~/Desktop/The Door.desktop'`, that is, if your desktop is named "Desktop" (depends on your language).

Comment: hmmm, think I found a difference. The little yellow one on rightclick has no 'open with...' option, whereas all normal foldera do. Shall I cut it?