# Unity 7 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04

When I create a starter file, unity does not display the icon with the name

[image: Desktop display]

Is it because of Unity or Ubuntu with gnome?

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you miss starters in the desktop-environment you'd might want to look copy the *.desktop-files to ~/.local/share/applications/ and then edit them.

Comment: you also don't have executable rights on these files. but what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have all the rights for folders and starters, everyone of the starters has "execute" permission. This is happening with any starter that I create.

Comment: This is also happening with starters created by PlayonLinux or Steam.

Comment: still (mostly) all "starters" show in the menus? right?  what are you trying to achieve? a *.desktop-file is not like an *.exe-file in Windows; perhaps read these two, then you might better understand: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application https://askubuntu.com/questions/117341/how-can-i-find-desktop-files

Comment: @db429 > What menu? What I am showing here, I put a link to /usr/share/applications on my desktop to have easy access to all applications. Under 16.04, there was no problems, I could see the icons and the name of the application. Under 18.04 the display is as the image above, without icons nor proper name for the applications.

Comment: See my answer to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the unity shell and changed back to the gnome one, and discovered the you can create "bookmarks" on Unity files display which appears on the left side of the window [image: Display of the "Bookmark Applications"]